# How to work with different time zone in Salesforce Apex

Tags: apex, datetime

Lets Say i have a location Object which stores multiple location details.

In location object we have fields :

TimeZone - Field 1
Opening Time - Field 2
Closing Time - Field 3

My Salesforce org timezone follow America/Los_Angeles time zone.

Lets say our location object has multiple records into it with different timezone and different time.

My problem statement is that whenever :

Time>opening time && Time < closing time

I have to execute a apex class via a scheduler class.

How can i convert my system time to that location record timezone ? So that i can validate my above logic and trigger an apex class ?

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce internally stores datetimes in the GMT (UTC+0) timezone and then converts to the user's timezone on display.

So as long as you keep working in GMT, you don't need to worry about the timezone at all.

I.e. if the records for a given timezone are entered by users in that timezone, then you can simply do

```
// Gets you the current date/time in GMT
Datetime rightNow = Datetime.now();

if(openingTime < rightNow && rightNow < closingTime) {
    // do work
}
```

If records for a given timezone can be entered by users outside of that timezone, then you need to do some corrections to remove the influence of the user's timezone and apply the desired timezone.
e.g.

```
// You'll probably need to do additional work to be able to do this comparison
if(UserInfo.getTimeZone() != record.Timezone__c) {
    // Convert the datetime to GMT to remove the influence of the user's timezone
    Datetime datetimeGMT = Datetime.valueOfGmt(record.Opening_Time__c.formatGmt('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'));

    // Then apply the desired timezone
    // Assuming Timezone__c is something like "America/Chicago"
    record.Opening_Time__c = Datetime.valueOf(datetimeGMT.format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', record.Timezone__c));

    // Alternatively, get the difference between both timezones and GMT
    //   (which gives you a difference in milliseconds) then just
    //  divide by 1000 and .addSeconds()
    // Use the same datetime for getting both offsets
    // It can matter which Datetime you use (around the 
    //   standard time/daylight time transitions), so using the record's
    //   opening/closing times is probably more reliable
    //Datetime dtNow = Datetime.now();

    // Multiplying the user's timezone offset by -1 removes the influence of
    //   the user's timezone (gets us to GMT)
    // Adding the target timezone (be it ahead of or behind GMT) gets us to
    //   our desired timezone
    //Integer tzDiff = UserInfo.getTimeZone().getOffset(dtNow) * -1 + TimeZone.getTimeZone(record.Timezone__c).getOffset(dtNow);

    // I don't believe that Salesforce stores milliseconds in Datetime fields
    // The Integer.valueOf() bit is just a safeguard
    //record.Opening_Time__c.addSeconds(Integer.valueOf(tzDiff / 1000));

    // repeat for Closing_Time__c
}
```

That correction would need to be applied every time the opening or closing time is changed (and when it's initially set).

If the record's timezone changes, then I'd prefer the timezone offset approach over the format/formatGMT approach. I.e. assume the opening/closing times are correct and just add the difference between the record's old timezone and its new timezone.

In fact, since it's so easy to mess up conversions to/from GMT, I think I'd prefer the timezone offset approach in all situations.